# For/Foreach Sql Server Para Cada Dado Distinto de uma Coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso executar um comando **SQL** para dar um Update numa tabela, A intenção deste update seria atualizar uma coluna com numero sequencial por empresa, Ex: 
Tenho uma tabela Venda nessa tabela tenho a coluna EmpresaId para cada empresa eu pretendo criar uma sequencia de venda tipo Empresa1 venda 1,2,3... Empresa 2 venda 1,2,3 e assim vai o ID nao respeita essa ordem, Pois bem o problema esta no seguinte, Criei a coluna e preciso dar um update que faça isso para os registros que ja existem, Consegui com o seguinte código:

```
DECLARE @NumeroSequencia int
SET @NumeroSequencia = 0
UPDATE Venda
SET @NumeroSequencia = NumeroSequencia = @NumeroSequencia + 1 where 
EmpresaID = 1
```

Porém onde esta o EmpresaID = 1 eu queria fazer algo tipo um foreach no exemplo porém em Sql:

```
--MONTA UMA LISTA COM OS IDS DE CADA EMPRESA CADASTRADA
declare listaEmpresas = select id from empresa

--PARA CADA EMPRESA EXECUTA O UPDATE COM A SEQUENCIA DAS VENDAS
foreach (var item in listaEmpresas){
DECLARE @NumeroSequencia int
SET @NumeroSequencia = 0
UPDATE Venda
SET @NumeroSequencia = NumeroSequencia = @NumeroSequencia + 1 where 
EmpresaID = item --AQUI SERIA O ID DE CADA EMPRESA SEGUINDO O FOREACH
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proponho uma solução que não utiliza laços (pelo menos não o faz explicitamente).

Começamos com a definição de uma tabela exemplo e com o carregamento de alguns registos.

```
CREATE TABLE #Vendas 
(
   VendaID        INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
   EmpresaID      INT,
   ProdutoID      INT,
   Quantidade     INT,
   DataVenda      DATE,
   --Nova coluna com ID de venda por empresa
   EmpresaVendaID INT,
);

--Carregar alguns registos na tabela 
INSERT INTO #Vendas(EmpresaID, ProdutoID, Quantidade, DataVenda)VALUES
(1, 1, 2, '2017-01-01'),
(1, 2, 2, '2017-02-01'),
(1, 2, 3, '2017-03-01'),
(1, 1, 5, '2017-04-01'),
(2, 1, 5, '2017-01-01'),
(2, 1, 4, '2017-02-01');

--SELECT * FROM #Vendas;
```

Antes do UPDATE a coluna EmpresaVendaID mostra NULL para todos registos:

```
VendaID EmpresaID   ProdutoID   Quantidade  DataVenda    EmpresaVendaID
1       1           1           2           01.01.2017   NULL
2       1           2           2           01.02.2017   NULL
3       1           2           3           01.03.2017   NULL
4       1           1           5           01.04.2017   NULL
5       2           1           5           01.01.2017   NULL
6       2           1           4           01.02.2017   NULL
```

Agora vamos actualizar a tabela. A ideia é gerar uma sequência para cada EmpresaID, sequência esta que começa sempre no 1. Pode ter que alterar ligeiramente a invocação da função ROW_NUMBER dependendo da estrutura da sua tabela. Neste caso eu assumo a existência de uma coluna que é chave primária na tabela #Vendas (VendaID).

```
UPDATE Vd
   SET EmpresaVendaID = Seq.Sequencia
  FROM #Vendas Vd
 INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT VendaID, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpresaID ORDER BY VendaID) Sequencia
        FROM #Vendas
  ) Seq
    ON Seq.VendaID = Vd.VendaID
;
```

Alternativa mais concisa

```
UPDATE Vd
   SET EmpresaVendaID = Sequencia
  FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpresaID ORDER BY VendaID) Sequencia FROM #Vendas ) Vd
;

--SELECT * FROM #Vendas;
```

Após o UPDATE este será o resultado:

```
VendaID EmpresaID   ProdutoID   Quantidade  DataVenda    EmpresaVendaID
1       1           1           2           01.01.2017   1
2       1           2           2           01.02.2017   2
3       1           2           3           01.03.2017   3
4       1           1           5           01.04.2017   4
5       2           1           5           01.01.2017   1
6       2           1           4           01.02.2017   2
```

Fica [aqui](http://rextester.com/XDK58875) o link para o código

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução possível seria utilizar a função [ROW_NUMBER() com Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) dentro de uma [Common_Table_Expression (CTE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) para gerar o sequencial de venda por empresa e, posteriormente, atualizar a tabela de Venda. A query ficaria assim:

```
with Venda_Cte (VendaID, NumeroSequencia)
as
(
  --query cte usando a função ROW_NUMBER com partition para gerar
  --o sequencial da venda para cada empresa
  select VendaID
         ,row_number() over (partition by EmpresaID order by VendaID)
    from Venda
)
--atualizando a tabela Venda com o sequencial da cte
update Venda
   set NumeroSequencia = Venda_Cte.NumeroSequencia  
  from Venda 
  join Venda_Cte on Venda.VendaID = Venda_Cte.VendaID;
```